# XYZ - is an object, interface or union type field. Leaf selections on objects, interfaces, and unions without subfields are disallowed

Tags: graphql, mutation, hotchocolate

Running this Mutation GraphQL query:

```
mutation {
    addProduct (input: { name: "Salad Roll", description : "Tasty Salad Roll" })
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> "errors": [         {           "message": "`addProduct` is an object, interface
> or union type field. Leaf selections on objects, interfaces, and
> unions without subfields are disallowed.",

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to return a value:

```
mutation {
    addProduct (input: { name: "Salad Roll", description : "Tasty Salad Roll" })
    {
        product
        {
        id
        }
    }
}
```